# Download audios from Firebase (Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

people of StackOverflow.

Recently I finish a course of Android Studio andd in classes we begin to  work with Firebase. I managed that my application reproduce audios in mp3 from the database, but now I would like to share it in another application, for it, I have done this:

```
this.stRef  = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("audios/audioname.mp3");

    File localFile = null;
    String downloadedaudio="";
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("audioname", ".mp3");
        downloadedaudio = localFile.getPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    stRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Downloaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Failed to Download"+exception,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

The app download a temp file, i check it in Android Studio file explorer, but then i does not share anything:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadedaudio);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartir sonido en: "));

}
```

Any idea of what i am doing wrong?
Thank you.